# Flyway changes performed in previous migration script are not visible to next migrations scripts

Tags: spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

In a spring-based project, I'm using flyway as a database migration tool.
I encounter very strange behavior. Suppose that I have 1 to n migration scripts to execute (mix between JDBC and SQL-based scripts). Flyway performs successfully a sequence of scripts but it stuck suddenly on script n-3 because it is not able to see changes performed in previous scripts. Strangely when I restarted my JAR and continue the migration process, the previous changes become visible to the stuck script and the error disappear.
Noting that I use Spring Data to implement my java based migration scripts.

Comment: I'm guessing you have some transaction not commited from n-4 to n-3. You should probably stick to SQL or JDBC to avoid this

Comment: thanks grekier for the reply, I start every sql file with Begin transaction and enclose it with commit and in java based script I add @transactional annotation to migrate() method .This could be the cause of my problem ?

Comment: My knowledge falls short here but I'm pretty sure that the context for the transaction is not the same and I guess that @Transactional might commit after the next SQL file has already started running...